# How can I pass a variable to a function here?

Tags: c

I use qsort from stdlib.h,

```
void qsort (void* base, size_t num, size_t size,
            int (*compar)(const void*,const void*));
```

in the following way:

```
void myfun (float *arr, int n, float c) // value of c is changeable
{
...// some code
qsort(float *arr, n, sizeof(float), compareme);
...// some code
}
```

with

```
int compareme (const void * a, const void * b)
{
  float tmp = f((float*)a,  (float*)b, c );  // f is some function, and how can I pass c here?
  if (tmp < 0) return -1;
  if (tmp == 0) return 0;
  if (tmp > 0) return 1;
}
```

how can I make `c` usable in `compareme` here?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't, because [tag:C] isn't lexically scoped. If you can switch to [tag:C++], you may create a compare object, which includes `c`.

Comment: Thanks, I can only use c

Answer (score 4):

Many resort to using a (nasty) global variable.

It is too bad that qsort() doesn't include an extra void pointer argument that is just passed to the user-supplied compar() function. I ended up writing my own qsort() to overcome this limitation.

Prototype:

```
int myQsort(
    void  *arrayBase,
    size_t elements,
    size_t elementSize,
    int(*compar)(const void *, const void *, void *callerArg),
    void *callerArg
    );
```

This allows me to pass all kinds of structures (cast to void *) to my compar() fn.

Comment: I think a global var can be fine if you make sure it is thread local. Non-portable qsort_r http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3.html

Answer (score 4):

If you happen to be using Glibc (i.e., Linux) you can use `qsort_r`:

```
int compareme (const void *a, const void *b, void *data)
{
  float c = *(float *)data;
  float tmp = f((float*)a,  (float*)b, c);
  if (tmp < 0) return -1;
  if (tmp == 0) return 0;
  if (tmp > 0) return 1;
}
```

then call

```
qsort_r(float *arr, n, sizeof(float), compareme, &c);
```

You have to define the preprocessor macro `_GNU_SOURCE` *before* including any headers to get this (e.g. with `-D_GNU_SOURCE`) to get this function, and it will restrict your program's portability.

Otherwise, you'll have to use global or thread-local storage, or write your own sort function.